# Excluding files in glob.glob()

Tags: python, glob

I have text files in a folder I need to iterate through and pull data from using python. To get all the path names I am using glob.glob(), except that I need to exclude any files that have 'ER' int he name. After looking around I found the [!_] command, however it is not working. Below is my exact code that is still returning 'ER' files.

```
files = glob.glob('*[!ER]*.txt')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ones you have your list of files you can use list comprehension to filter and remove any files that contain 'ER'.

```
files = [f for f in files if 'ER' not in f]
```

Comment: That works perfectly! Thanks. I was hoping I could make it one line, but the regular expression for glob is not great at exclusion.

Comment: You could make it one line `files = [f for f in glob.glob('*.txt') if 'ER' not in f]`

Answer (score 1):

There are other libraries that can do exclusions. For instance [wcmatch](https://github.com/facelessuser/wcmatch/) (full disclosure, I'm the author of it) allows you to use exclusion patterns (when enabled via a flag). Exclusion patterns are given along with a normal patterns, and it will filter the returned list of files:

```
from wcmatch import glob
glob.glob(['*.txt', '!*ER*.txt'], flags=glob.N)
```

Here is a real world example:

```
from wcmatch import glob
>>> glob.glob(['*.md'], flags=glob.N)
['LICENSE.md', 'README.md']
>>> glob.glob(['*.md', '!*EA*.md'], flags=glob.N)
['LICENSE.md']
```